Frequent vs often, before vs after
Suppose the trash gets collected in your neighborhood on Wednesday, and it did, but now it is Friday and you see the trash getting collected again.
As a native speaker of English (California) I would say either - and they're both equally good to my ears:

Hey, there is more frequent trash collection!, or
Hey, there is trash collection more often!

But I would definitely not say either of the following because they sound wrong:

Hey, there is more often trash collection!, or
Hey, there is trash collection more frequent!

What's going on here?  (Is it parts of speech, or direct object vs indirect object, or what?  Like, I suppose, many native speakers of English and no other language, my knowledge of grammar correctness is implicit, and I don't know even the right terms, really.)

Seems to me that there was an extra trash collection on Friday.

Frequent is an adjective, often is an adverb.

As noted in the comments, you're comparing the adjective frequent with the adverb often, which is why the word order is different and you feel the tension of swapping them.
One way to help understand this is to look just at the phrases. A frequent collection is the same as a slow collection, or a free collection, or a noisy collection. But it's not the same as an often collection. We would have to say that something was often collected, and now it's grammatically linked to a verb, not a noun.
Another way to see the difference is to realise that frequent does have a corresponding adverb: frequently. If you directly switched often and frequently it would make sense. Compare:

There is trash collection more often.
There is trash collection more frequently.

Both of these mean:

The trash is collected more often/frequently.

